# ZeppOS app on T-Rex2 - receiving gps data

Tags: navigation, gps, zeppos

Is there any chance to receive GPS data in app on T-Rex 2 ? I want write my own "navigation app" for this watch.

Answer (score 0):

GPS data will be available probably sometime in 2023. Currently, there's no feature for GPS data on ZeppOS 1.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).